# Property Selection INCORRECT in dynamic content -Logic app Azure

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am writing a logic app. My schema looks like below.
[image]

i am able to select the dynamic content at each step. I am have 4 "for each" operations for the 4 arrays.

However when i test through postman ,
i get the error at " for each " step.
"InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for action 'For_each_items' at line '1' and column '1710': 'The template language expression 'triggerBody()?['Data']?['Orders_items']' cannot be evaluated because property 'Data' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you use postman to test, you need to select the body type as json：

[image]